# Setting Logger Implementation to Test Scope with Maven for IntelliJ

Tags: maven, testing, logging, intellij-idea

For automated tests of an API, I need to have an implementation of a logger present. But the logger is supposed to not ship with the API itself. To that end I set up the relevant part of the `pom.xml` of the API module itself like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I manually run maven from the command line the test where the logger is relevant passes. But when I run the test file from within Intellij I get the following error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I have spent several hours now trying to figure out what is wrong and followed multiple tutorials. None actually covered the sort of setup I need though and so I am still stuck with this error.

Do you know what the actual problem is here and how to set this up correctly?

Comment: For what it's worth, that exact setup works in Eclipse. Either it's an IDE thing, or your local setup doesn't 'see' the dependency (maybe using a Maven profile or something)